# Probability of intersection in conditional probability

Tags: probability

**Suppose there are seven keys**:

- 5 red keys.
- 2 green keys.

Only **one** of those seven keys opens a lock.

If for the experiment "Choose a random key and see if it opens the lock", I define the following events:

- A: "The chosen key opens the lock".
- G: "The right key is green".

And knowing that:

- The probability of A is: 1/7.
- The probability of G is: 2/7.
- The probability of A knowing that the key is green is: 1/2

According to the relationship in conditional probability, the probability of A intersection G is: 1/7

Because p(A|G) = A intersection G / p(G)

But according to the probability of an intersection of independent events, the probability of A intersection G should be: 1/7 * 2/7 = 2/49

I do not understand why I get different values.

Comment: $G$ is not an event here. Did you mean to define: "G: The chosen key is green"?

Comment: I must stop now. Later I will have a look at your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> G:"The right key is green"

This can not be recognized as an event linked with the experiment that you descibe. There are seven keys and one of them opens a lock and this key allready has its color: it is red or it is green.

Then you can ask questions like: if the right key is green, then what is the probability that it is picked? In mathematical notation something like: $$\Pr(A\mid G)=?$$

This notation is disputable, since - as I said - $G$ is not an event here. You can compare it with  something like $\Pr(D=5\mid R)$ where $D=5$ stands for the event that a thrown die gives $5$ and $R$ stands for: "it rains at the moment". Then $R$ not restricting/influencing the experiment.

The color of the correct key will have no influence here. So we get: $$P(A\mid G)=P(A)=\frac17$$

In fact the knowledge about its color is not affecting the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite a random experiment as it is determined in advance which key opens the lock. So, your calculations involving G are illegal.